# Set item at the top right corner using flex

Tags: html, css

I'm new in CSS and I want to create a menu at the top-right corner of my site. so I tried it using flex.

Reference image
[image]

First I created an overlay so it should be the blank background and inside it the classic hamburger. I tried:

```css
html {
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar {
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right-container {
  display: flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.overlay {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav {
  flex: 50%;
}

.nav {
  flex: 50%;
  .nav-item {
    .nav-link {
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 36px;
      padding: 1rem;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: $clr-carbonLT;
      border-radius: 0.5rem;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
      position: relative;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
      }
      &.active {
        color: $clr-carbon;
        &::after {
          content: '';
          transform: translateY(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="nav-link btn" (click)="toggleSidebar()"><i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i></button>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the design and alignment are not correct, how can I solve that? Regards

As comments below I updated my code and it works, it aligns the menu to the right correctly, it only works if I remove `<div class="overlay">`, if I add it, just align to left again? how can I align it correctly with overlay?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you want the overlay to do. The name "overlay" suggests a full-screen layer on top of something else - like a dark modal window backdrop. But in your css the overlay element is 50px x 50px. If you can minimize your code to the bare minimum, that would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, and what should be a correct name for what I'm doing? @Cornelius

Comment: I don't know. Other than the need to move the icon to the right, the question is vague. I don't know what "align it correctly" means.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing css in `.right-container` :

```css
.right-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

All that `justify-content` does is move the `.overlay` element over to the right.

Comment: I update my question with the changes